# Selenium Python Locating a button that contains a string?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Is there any way of locating a button where the text on the button includes a known string? for example, i want to locate the button that says 'Buy now' but there may be text or blank spaces either side of it:

[image]

I only know that it would contain 'Buy It Now', any help appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Selenium has a number of methods for finding elements by text.  You could use xpath as follows:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[translate(text(), ' &#13;&#10;&#09;&#xa;', '')='Buy It Now']"));
```